# Should I use a ferrite core on my AC adapter?

Tags: adapter, ferrite

I'm using an AC adapter for a port replicator (it meets the voltage and provides more amps) which doesn't have the ferrite core the original one had. Should I put one of these ferrite cores on it or won't it make a difference?

[image: Ferrite cores]

[image: Connector]

Comment: It won't make much difference if you put it over *both* the wires.

Comment: It depends. Is the power supply adaptor or laptop causing significant common mode emissions across the radio spectrum?

Comment: yes you should. there's literally no downside and the part came with one, at extra cost, which they never do for no reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clamp ferrites (a.k.a. ferrite sleeves) are placed around both of the wires for common-mode noise cancellation on both directions (supply line to the equipment and vice versa).

Just because there's no clamp placed, doesn't mean the equipment needs one.

- The equipment may have been designed properly to meet the respective conducted and radiated EMI requirements, even without any clamp whatsoever.
- Or the manufacturer may not have cared about EMC and tried to save a few pence.

Some equipment are sold as sets i.e. end equipment itself with its power supply. If the end equipment (port replicator, in your case) is prone to the supply line noise then its power supply might have a ferrite clamp. This might explain `the ferrite core the original one had`. That's why the manufacturers always say "use the recommended/approved power supply".

Now,

- Your port replicator may experience some disturbances coming from possible supply-line common-mode noise. In this case, placing a random clamp ferrite may not help as you don't know what frequency range (or component) from the range of 150k-30M or 30M-1G causes the problem. A clamp is effective at a relatively narrow frequency range i.e. they can't be expected to suppress the entire range. That's why some equipment come with multiple clamps.
- Or your port replicator may work properly, so you may not need to place a clamp.

Comment: Can the ferrite core size provide a clue about the impedance?
The ferrite core which was in the original AC adapter was around the same size as the small one in the picture.